# How to get different menu items showing for admins vs users

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio, roles

I'm trying to setup my site where all of the links show for the admin role and a limited amount show for the  user role.

Here is my sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode >
    <siteMapNode url="fake1.aspx" title="Example A"  description="Example" roles="user">
      <siteMapNode url="fake2.aspx" title="Example 1"  description="Example" roles="user" />
      <siteMapNode url="fake3.aspx" title="Example 2"  description="Example" roles="user" />
      <siteMapNode url="fake4.aspx" title="Example 3"  description="Example" roles="user" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="fake5.aspx" title="Example B"  description="Example" roles="user">
      <siteMapNode url="fake6.aspx" title="Example 1"  description="Example" roles="user" />
      <siteMapNode url="fake7.aspx" title="Example 2"  description="Example" roles="user" />
      <siteMapNode url="fake8.aspx" title="Example 3"  description="Example" roles="user" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="fake9.aspx" title="Example C"  description="Example" roles="user">
      <siteMapNode url="fake10.aspx" title="Example 1"  description="Example" roles="user" />
      <siteMapNode url="fake11.aspx" title="Example 2"  description="Example" roles="user" />
      <siteMapNode url="fake12.aspx" title="Example 3"  description="Example" roles="user"/>
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="fake13.aspx" title="Example D"  description="Example" roles="admin">
      <siteMapNode url="fake14.aspx" title="Example 1"  description="Example" roles="admin" />
      <siteMapNode url="fake15.aspx" title="Example 2"  description="Example" roles="admin" />
      <siteMapNode url="fake16.aspx" title="Example 3"  description="Example" roles="admin" />
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Here is my menu server control:

```
<div id="menuBar">
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" StaticDisplayLevels="2"
        Orientation="Horizontal" >
    </asp:Menu>
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

And here is a screenshot of my roles:

[image]

From the tutorials I have been reading roles="" is supposed to take care of the links access on a per role basis but nothing is happening on my site. Users and Admins are seeing the same thing. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the user is in the right role before displaying admin related content: -

```
if (Membership.GetUser() != null && Page.User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    //User is an admin
}
```

Comment: I am not displaying the menu via c#, can I hide or show parts of the sitemap using c#?

Comment: You can swap out the datasource based on the role or filter it before assigning it to the menu